MongoDB Atlas AWS CDK Deploy Error "No region exists"
Getting "No region exists" error when trying to deploy MongoDB serverless via AWS CDK v2 to us-east-1 or us-west-2.
CDK deploy error: "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/{myProjectId}/serverless POST: HTTP 400 Bad Request (Error code: "INVALID_REGION") Detail: No region exists for provider AWS.
Have followed setup instructions carefully:
https://github.com/mongodb/awscdk-resources-mongodbatlas
"awscdk-resources-mongodbatlas": "3.3.0"
Bootstrap:

activationTypes: ['Project', 'ServerlessInstance', 'ServerlessPrivateEndpoint', 'ProjectIpAccessList']
IAM role created

Project API key:

opened to all IPs
permissions = Project Owner + Organization Owner

AWS Secret created:

profile = test
secret name = cfn/atlas/profile/test
API Key (public key and private key)

Code:

Have tried both L1 and L3 constructs.
e.g. new atlas.AtlasServerlessBasic etc.


Specifying a "MongoDB Atlas" region name resolved this error.
A MongoDB Atlas region name is NOT the same as an AWS region name:
AWS = us-east-1
MongoDB = US_EAST_1
*Note the underscore in the MongoDB region name.
this.serverlessInstance = new atlas.CfnServerlessInstance(this, 'ServerlessInstance', {
    name,
    projectId,
    profile,
    continuousBackupEnabled,
    providerSettings: {
        providerName: atlas.ServerlessInstanceProviderSettingsProviderName.SERVERLESS,
        // MongoDB region name syntax is different to AWS.
        // AWS: us-east-1, MongoDB: US_EAST_1
        // https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/amazon-aws/#std-label-amazon-aws
        regionName: US_EAST_1
    },
    terminationProtectionEnabled
});

